# Deleting file geodatabase table with quotes in name using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase, table, delete

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2.

I somehow managed to accidentally rename a table in my file geodatabase with quotation marks in the name. Trying to open it will yield a `Failed to open table.` error.

[image]

[image]

I am able to `right click --> delete` this table, but then it always reappears when I close / open Pro. I can also make it reappear just by refreshing the file geodatabase.

How can I delete this table permanently?

Comment: Well, for sure, you can Copy everything else out into a new FGDB, but it might take a special tool from Tech Support to do any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to try :

1. Export your file GDB as XML (in catalog right click on it and select
   Export > geodatabase to XML workspace, select the option to export
   data not    only the structure)
2. Open the resulting XML in a text editor and use the search and
   replace fonction to replace all occurrence of `nonnull_"04_05_2023"` by
   `nonnull_04_05_2023` (or any other valid table name of your choice) and save the XML
3. Create en new empty geodatabase and import the modified XML (in
   catalog right click on your new database and select Import> XML
   workspace)

After step 3 you should get an exact copy of your original database but the problematic table will now have a valid name and won't pose any problem when opening it or deleting it